# Download youtube playlist on clients computer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to download youtube playlist by using masih package. But currently it is downloading on server. I want to to download it on client's computer.

I tried to give different directory to it but it is not working.

```
public function download(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            "videourl" => 'required'
        ]);
        $url = $request->input('videourl');
        $data = [
            'url' => $url
        ];
        switch ($this->detectWebsite($url)){
            case 'youtube':
                if($this->detectPlaylist($url) == false){
                    $yt = new \YouTubeDownloader();
                    $links = $yt->getDownloadLinks($url);
                    $id = $yt->extractId($url);
                    $content = file_get_contents("http://youtube.co/get_video_info?video_id=" . $id);
                    parse_str($content, $ytarr);
                    $img = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/".$id."/0.jpg";
                    $data['links'] = $links;
                    $data['thumbnail'] = $img;
                    $data['title'] = @$ytarr['title'];
                    return view('download.youtube-video',$data);
                }else{
                    $playlist_id = $this->detectPlaylist($url);

                  $youtube = new YoutubeDownloader($playlist_id);

                  $result = $youtube->getInfo();
                  set_time_limit(300000);



                  $youtube->download();
                  header('Content-type: application/json');

                    $url = "https://www.youtube.com/list_ajax?style=json&action_get_list=1&list=".$playlist_id;

                    $playlistData = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true);
                    $data['playlist'] = $playlistData;


                    return view('download.youtube-playlist',$data);
                }
                break;

            case 'unknown':
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors(["Invalid Url"]);
                break;
        }
    }
```

I want to download it on client's computer